# Changing point color on matplolib and basemap not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am having some issue with getting my data onto a map with Basemap and having those points change in color.  I have read many different things online about how to do this, but I still get a map with no points.  Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
from IPython.display import SVG, display_svg
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as co

d3data = pickle.load( open( "9_28_2015to10_04_2015.pickle", "rb" ) )

lons = d3data['longitude'].tolist()
lats = d3data['latitude'].tolist()
normcts = co.Normalize(d3data['GrossCounts'])

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

m = Basemap(projection='cass', lat_0 = 40.108004, lon_0 = -88.228878,
    resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.1,
    llcrnrlon=-88.238399, llcrnrlat=40.097942,
    urcrnrlon=-88.219345, urcrnrlat=40.116158)

m.drawcountries()
m.fillcontinents(color='white')
m.drawmapboundary()
m.readshapefile('mhj_shapes/lines', 'lines')
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
norm = co.Normalize(vmin=d3data['GrossCounts'].min(),
    vmax=d3data['GrossCounts'].max())
pointcolors = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, cmap)

for i in range(0, len(d3data)): 
    col = pointcolors.to_rgba(d3data['GrossCounts'][i])
    x,y = m(d3data['longitude'][i],d3data['latitude'][i])
    m.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o', s=10, color=col, cmap=cmap)

plt.show()
```

My problem is that my shape file generates a map just fine, but I don't get any points on top of it.  I want to plot the dataframe columns `d3data['GrossCounts']` on top of the map and have the color scale with the (integer) value of `d3data['GrossCounts']`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

It turns out that this is described in [`map.scatter` on basemap not displaying markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107404/map-scatter-on-basemap-not-displaying-markers) (although I was not searching for the right terms when I googled in here).  Here is the change that finally worked:

```
m.drawcountries()
m.fillcontinents(color='white', zorder=0) # <--zorder!!!
m.drawmapboundary()
m.readshapefile('mhj_shapes/lines', 'lines')
cmap = plt.cm.jet

x, y = m(lons, lats)
norm = co.Normalize(vmin=d3data.GrossCounts.min(), vmax=250)
pointcolors = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, cmap)
col = pointcolors.to_rgba(d3data.GrossCounts)
m.scatter(x, y, s=10, c=col, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

I don't know why I never saw zorder in any of the online examples that I had found, but adding this makes sure that the map itself is sent to the back so the points are brought to the front.  Thank you, all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to test without your data/shape file etc, but the problem could be your for loop. Maybe try without the loop:

```
col = pointcolors.to_rgba(d3data['GrossCounts'])
x, y = m(d3data['longitude'], d3data['latitude'])
m.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=10, color=col, cmap=cmap)
```

i.e. if I do:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))

m = Basemap(projection='cass', lat_0 = 0, lon_0 = 0,
    resolution = 'l', area_thresh = 0.1,
    llcrnrlon=-10, llcrnrlat=-10,
    urcrnrlon=10, urcrnrlat=10)

m.drawcountries()
m.fillcontinents(color='white')
m.drawmapboundary()
#m.readshapefile('mhj_shapes/lines', 'lines')
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlBu_r

x, y = m([0, 5], [0, 5])
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2]})
norm = co.Normalize(vmin=df.a.min(), vmax=df.a.max())
pointcolors = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, cmap)
col = pointcolors.to_rgba(df.a)
m.scatter(x, y, s=10, color=col)

plt.show()
```

I get:

[image: map with scatter plot]

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Interesting.  I plugged in your code and still see no points on my plot.  [link] (https://www.flickr.com/photos/130107678@N05/shares/4896Z1).  I can see that the variables (like col) are populating correctly.  It is something in the plotting that I must be doing wrong.

Comment: I guess you've already checked, but what are the min/max of d3data['longitude'] and d3data['latitude'] ?

Comment: I have checked and confirmed that they are within the bounding box set up in the map.

Comment: What happens if you copy and paste my simplified example?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot put the figure in because my rep score is not yet high enough.  :(  But if you click the flickr link above, you can see it.  It is just a map of the roads and what not, but no points on it.

Comment: If I look at the link I see a bigger map. I mean try the second block of code in my answer. Just to check that at least that works as it did for me.

Comment: Ah.  Yes, I got the same thing as you in that code blurb.

Comment: And FWIW...if I just set color='k', it still does not plot the points on the map itself.

Comment: If i set color='k' then I get black points. What versions of the packages are you using?

Comment: I found that I was on Basemap version 1.0.7, so I upgraded to 1.0.8, but it still did not fix it.  I also am on matplotlib 1.3.1.  And just to show I am not totally smoking something, it works if I do not want to overlay points on the basemap (as in, just using plt.scatter), as shown here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/130107678@N05/shares/FzK286 .